# Aquaris M10 File Manage Network folder crash

Tags: crash, filemanager, aquaris, m10

Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-13)
File Manager App

I can use every other folder in the "File Manager" app. 
But when I try to access the network to reach my server files, the app just closes.

I've tried to "unlock" full access. Still the same result.
The "Goto" feature won't accept an smb address

I've got all my updates.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I've found this has been reported in launchpad at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-filemanager-app/+bug/1609051 , Please go there and verify if it affects you too.